# Windows 7 doesn't request MTU from DHCP server; what is it thinking?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, ethernet, mtu

My computer's Ethernet adapter uses 1,500 byte Ethernet frames. Normally this means that my **Local Area Connection's** MTU is `1500` bytes.

But my (IPv4) connection to the Internet has some overhead. This means that my actual MTU when communicating to the Internet is `1492`. This is causing all the regular problems that exist with mis-configured interface MTU.

## The Router Can Fix It

Obviously i **could** use `netsh`, and override my network interface with a custom MTU. But i don't want to do that. My router's DHCP server already knows that the MTU is `1492`. If asked, the DHCP Server will respond with DHCP option 26:

- 26 **MTU Interface** = `1492`

So it was driving me nuts why the DHCP server isn't *telling* my Windows 7 machine the MTU setting as one of the items it returns in the **DHCP offer**:

- 54 **DHCP Server Identifier** = `192.168.1.1`
- 51 **IP Address Lease Time** = `2 hours`
- 1 **Subnet Mask** = `255.255.255.0`
- 15 **Domain Name** = `example.local`
- 3 **Router** = `192.168.1.1`
- 6 **Domain Name Server** = `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`, `74.82.42.42`

No **MTU Interface**! So my machine's Ethernet is stuck at `1500` bytes.

## DHCP server's did what it's supposed to do

It took more digging, but i realized that DHCP Server's only give what the client **asked** for. During my Windows 7 **DHCP Discover**, Windows 7 enumerates the list of all the DHCP options it would like returned:

- 1 **Subnet Mask**
- 15 **Domain Name**
- 3 **Router**
- 6 **Domain Name Server**
- 44 **NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Server**
- 46 **NetBIOS over TCP/IP Node Type**
- 47 **NetBIOS over TCP/IP Scope**
- 31 **Perform Router Discovery**
- 33 **Static Route**
- 121 **Classless Static Route**
- 249 **Classless Static Route (Microsoft)**
- 43 **Vendor-Specific Information**

Windows 7 isn't even **asking** for the **MTU**!

## It must know what it's doing

Windows must have a *reason* why it's not asking for the MTU; but i don't know what it is. At first i thought it was because it was using [Path Maximum MTU Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916746.aspx). But `PMTU` only works for TCP connections, uses the TCP `MSS` (Maximum Segment Size) option, and requires that the local `MSS` option be correct.

In my case the TCP MSS setting (which comes from the MTU option) is wrong. It is `1460 bytes`

```
  1500 interface MTU
-   20 bytes IP header = 1480 bytes
-   20 bytes TCP header
= 1460 bytes MSS
```

which is too high.

> **Note**: I can confirm Windows is using an **MSS** of 1460 bytes from a `SYN` packet, when a TCP connection is being established.

## If not PathMTU, then what?

What is Windows 7 thinking? What is the *intended* behavior here? What were the network stack developers at Microsoft thinking should happen?

Now pretend that my Internet MTU is actually 1472 (which it is), and pretend that my Ethernet adapter actually uses `8,192` byte Ethernet frames (which it does). What is a corporation supposed to do? Am i supposed to walk up to every machine in the enterprise and type:

```
>netsh interface ipv4 set interface interface="Local Area Connection" mtu=1472 store=persistent
```

That's not reasonable. And even if it were reasonable, it's not what i'm asking.

I'm trying to understand what Windows *wants* to have happen. i'm trying to understand how it *should* behave. i'm trying to learn something here. Pretend that my Internet gateway is a 576 byte ATM; how do i instruct Windows 7 machines that the MTU if they want to send to the Internet is 576 bytes?

## Bonus Reading

- [`EnablePMTUDiscovery` registry option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957539.aspx)
- [`MTU` registry option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938197.aspx)
- [How to Request Additional DHCP Options from a DHCP Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312468)
- [DHCP Server option to set interface-MTU option to lowest WAN interface value](https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/1867)

Comment: According to http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Miscellaneous/Q_21711433.html (right down the bottom) someone anecdotally reports that Windows doesn't ask for the MTU (which is what you're seeing). As far as what a corporation would do, they'd probably use Group Policy to run a script that would apply the changes.

Comment: For what a corporation would do, the router would have its outside MTU set properly after testing maximum mtu allowed with ping (typically 1380-1500). The inside, being pure ethernet would be 1500 and the Windows machines left alone as they communicate to the router on an ethernet network.

Comment: @FiascoLabs But what happens when the router drops packets destined for the Internet when they cannot fit out the pipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Path MTU is not TCP only and doesn't use MSS (though as you have surmised, MSS is derived from MTU).  Any hop that receives a packet too big to forward will send an `ICMP fragmentation needed` packet back to the origin.  This is part of layer 3 and is independent of TCP.

The problem with PMTU is that the incoming ICMP packets are often dropped or not forwarded to the origin, and so the origin does not know to reduce the packet size.

As your router knows that the next hop MTU is 1472, it should be sending PMTU packets to your clients.  You can check this with wireshark, and if it is not doing this, it needs fixing.

You have a couple of workarounds.  One is to set the inside interface of the router's MTU to 1472, which will mean it gets actioned before the router does any processing.  The other option is (if you can do it with your router) is to turn on the DF bit for every packet.  This is a pretty brutal workaround as any full size packets will end up as two separate packets, one small, one large, with the resultant overhead.

In a corporate setting, all three approaches may be used, but hard setting mtu on the router LAN interface is pretty common.

(I have never come across an instance where DHCP is used to mediate MTU, it wouldn't be the right place in most cases, because the internal MTU and border MTU often different, where you might use jumbo frames internally, but need to reduce to normal size for internet traffic)

Comment: i got my (mis)information about `Path MTU Discovery` relying on TCP MSS [from this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms883400.aspx). i see now that just read it wrong. Consulting [RFC1191 - Path MTU Discovery](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1191) would have been the better choice. Now i'm left to wonder why the local router isn't responding with [ICMP Destination Unreachable - Fragmentation needed but DF flag set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Destination_unreachable). pfSense just released version 2.1, and it doesn't send ICMP 3-4 :(

Comment: Is pfSense just dropping icmp unreachables perhaps?  This is often set as a "security" measure with some devices, but often causes more trouble than it saves.

Comment: i've been preparing screenshots and documentation for that very issue in pfSense. Unfortunately they are pretty testy is someone suggests an issue with *their* system. Then they'd likely suggest that i shouldn't be relying on ICMP notifications; as a lot of firewalls are misconfigured to block it. And finally that i should simply set the MTU on enterprise's LAN NICs.

Comment: Interface MTU is a defined part of the DHCP standard.  It's option 26: http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/bootp/option026.htm
Windows just chooses to ignore it

Comment: If you implement @Paul 's workarounds (even if all) and so end up leaving the client interface with the higher MTU you will come across some TLS handshake failures with very few partners. Still this is very annoying since you will have a hard time finding it as most connections (even with the exact same technology) work. Till now idk why this happens but I just came here because a windows server's connection to Backblaze B2 was failing due to MTU in a setup which used all workarounds. And I remember a similar case some years ago with PayPal's server. So just leaving this comment as heads up...